# discord.py - Is there a way to fix this invalid syntax error for picking a random date

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

so basically what I'm trying to do with discord.py is create a command that basically gives you a random date of 2022-01-01, to 2023-01-01. I think I have good code, but I get a invalid syntax error whenever I try running it. Here is my code.

```
import datetime
import random
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command(name='death')
async def death(ctx, *, user_that_dies:discord.User):
  await ctx.send(f'**PERSON**\n\n{user_that_dies:discord.User}\n\n**WHEN THEY ARE GOING TO DIE**\n\n{radar.random_datetime(start='2022-01-01', stop='2023-01-01')
}')
```

Comment: For future reference, if you're getting an exception, it is helpful if you include the exception traceback in your question.

Comment: Looks like you didn't `import radar`

Comment: Oh I did import radar but it still no matter what gave me an error saying "invalid syntax"

Comment: @DLG Can you post the full traceback? It's probably multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
await ctx.send(f'**PERSON**\n\n{user_that_dies:discord.User}\n\n**WHEN THEY ARE GOING TO DIE**\n\n{radar.random_datetime(start='2022-01-01', stop='2023-01-01')}')
```

This is invalid syntax because you're nesting single quotes inside another single quoted string, which you can't do.  Use double-quotes for the inner or outer quotes.

Comment: I changed the outer quotes to double-quotes, but it still gives a syntax error.

Comment: @DLG `{user_that_dies:discord.User}` might also be a problem.  The part after the colon is a type hint, but those are only used in parameter declarations.  Don't use them when you're just referring to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`random.random_datetime` isn't an actual function.

You can generate a random datetime in the range you want with something like this

```py
import random
from datetime import date, timedelta

def random_datetime():
    return date(2022, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=random.randint(0, 365))
```

Comment: I did this and changed the part where it says "{radar.random_datetime(start='2022-01-01', stop='2023-01-01}') to "{}random_datetime()", but it still gives an error.